# How to use react compiler in custom console react component

Tags: reactjs

Have Created my own editor in which we could write code in react.
Need to create a console component in which output from my editor must be shown.
For this initially, need to use react compiler to compile my code written in the editor?
how to use react compiler in my component?
?
On left bottom is my code editor I just want to see the output from my editor in console component that is on the right
[image]

Comment: I have added a sample Image for the same .Please refer the image

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. There's no such thing as React compiler. What do you want to compile?

Comment: Just want to create a component in which i have my own editor as shown in image on left hand side ,Just want output to be shown on component created .

Comment: something like https://codepen.io/

Comment: Hi! This was a long time. React can be written with vanilla JS and createElement, in this case you need to just evaluate the script. In order to use JSX, it needs to be compiled indeed. You can usebabel-standalone to compile it on client side, otherwise this would require to do API calls to a server which is a pain.